# How to specify mailbox I want in outlook command line?

Tags: command-line, outlook

for example, if I have two mailboxs in my outlook, one named "**mailbox - first, sur**", which is default one, the second one is named "**mailbox - first2, sur**"

How can I popup the outlook window for "**first2. sur**"? Right now, I only know of the command line `outlook.exe /select "outlook:inbox"` to popup my default inbox.

How can I popup the "**first2. sur**" inbox?

Answer (score 1):

After try in command line again and again, it found the answer by myself. :)
for example, if you want to popup the window for

> inbox\error

```
outlook /select "outlook:\\mailbox - first2, sur\inbox\error"
```